# Update json array values in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I'm plotting a graph using highchart but date in not properly displaying in x-axis so i need to parse the dates from the json response. I tried to manipulate the json date but not getting as expected.

```
This is my current json response

"linechart":[{
                "name":"Average Conversation Length (In minutes)",
                "data":[["2020,02,12",12],["2020,02,13",13]]
            },{
                 "name":"Average Number of Conversations",
                 "data":[["2020,02,12",10],["2020,02,13",21]]
            }]
```

This is my expected output

```
linechart: [{name: "Average Conversation Length (In minutes)",
            data: [[Date.UTC(2020, 02, 12), 12],[Date.UTC(2020, 02, 13), 13]]},
            {name: "Average Number of Conversations",
            data: [[Date.UTC(2020, 02, 12), 10],[Date.UTC(2020, 02, 13), 21]]}],
```

This is what i tried

```
    var arr1 = [];
var data = chartdata.linechart
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var obj = data[i];
    for (var key in obj){
      var value = obj[key];
      for (var value2 in value){
        var values = value[value2];
        arr1.push(Date.parse(values));
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = chartdata.linechart;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var obj = data[i];
  obj.data.forEach(d => {
    d[0] = Date.parse(d[0]);
  });
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `map` over the elements:

```js
let linechart = [
  {
    "name":"Average Conversation Length (In minutes)",
    "data":[["2020,02,12",12],["2020,02,13",13]]
},{
    "name":"Average Number of Conversations",
    "data":[["2020,02,12",10],["2020,02,13",21]]
}]

const res = linechart.map(o => {
    return {name: o.name, data: o.data.map( ([d,n]) => {
        return [Date.parse(d), n]
    })}
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this approach:

```
let jsonData = [{
  "name": "Average Conversation Length (In minutes)",
  "data": [
    ["2020,02,12", 12],
    ["2020,02,13", 13]
  ]
}, {
  "name": "Average Number of Conversations",
  "data": [
    ["2020,02,12", 10],
    ["2020,02,13", 21]
  ]
}];

jsonData.forEach(item => {
    item.data.forEach(data => {
        let date = data[0].split(',');
        
        data[0] = Date.UTC(date[0], date[1], date[2])
    })
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ucx6ojL2/